# Inject Container in my Repository Class

Tags: symfony

i try to inject Container in my RepositoryClass, but it does not work.

BaseRepository:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\ApplicationBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class BaseRepository implements ContainerAwareInterface
{

    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container=null)
    {
        echo "container";
        var_dump($container);
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
services:
    myapp.base_repository:
        class: MyApp\ApplicationBundle\Repository\BaseRepository
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ '@service_container' ] ]
```

DefaultController:

```
$baseRep = new BaseRepository();
```

The only output that i get, is the echo **FILE** from the BaseRepository Construct.
The second way that i tried, is to inject the GuzzleClient self (this is the reason why i tried to inject the container, because i need my guzzle-configuraton-settings.

services.yml

```
myapp.base_repository:
    class: MyApp\ApplicationBundle\Repository\BaseRepository
    arguments: ['@csa_guzzle.client.mce']
```

BaseRepository:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class BaseRepository
{
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        var_dump($client);
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}
```

But then i got the following error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   MyApp\ApplicationBundle\Repository\BaseRepository::__construct() must
>   be an instance of GuzzleHttp\Client, none given, called in
>   MyApp/src/Chameleon/DefaultBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on
>   line 20

Anyone know what i can do?

Thank you!

Comment: The new operator knows nothing about the dependency injection container.  You need to pull your service directly from the container.  From a controller that would be $repo = $this->get('myapp.base_repository');

Comment: After looking at what you are doing it seems like it would make more sense to create a service to do what you want, and inject the entity manager into that should you need to call repository functions.

Answer (score 1):

To get the class that is managed by the Service Container you have to use said container to get the service with that id `myapp.base_repository` as Twifty says:

```
$this->get('myapp.base_repository');
// or more generally in classes implementing ContainerAwareInterface:
$this->container->get('myapp.base_repository');
```

If you create a new instance yourself you will have to manage all dependencies:

```
// In your controller extending Symfony's Controller:
$repository = new BaseRepository();
$repository->setContainer($this->container);
```

Similarly if you inject a Guzzle-client into the repository you have to either retrieve the service from the container or create it yourself with all the dependencies:

```
// $this->get() assumes you are in the controller as well
$repositoryWithClientFromServiceContainer = new BaseRepository(
    $this->get('csa_guzzle.client.mce')
);
// This obviously works everywhere
$repositoryWithNewDefaultClient = new BaseRepository(
    new GuzzleHttp\Client()
);
```

Furthermore injecting the service container into a class violates the dependency inversion you try to achieve by using the Service Container in the first place. This means, instead of making your repository `ContainerAware` you should only add the services you need in that repository, not the whole container. Just as you do in the 2nd example with the Guzzle-client.

Some people argue it's okay for controllers to violate that principle, but I personally prefer [controller's being defined as services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html) to be able to quickly see which dependencies they have by looking at the constructor.

As a general rule I would avoid using the ContainerAwareInterface.

Comment: Agreed on your general rule.  It seems like the author's whole concept needs to be reversed - create a service and inject the entity manager into that.

Answer (score 0):

> Similarly if you inject a Guzzle-client into the repository you have
>   to either retrieve the service from the container or create it
>   yourself with all the dependencies:
>
> ```
> // $this->get() assumes you are in the controller as well
> $repositoryWithClientFromServiceContainer = new BaseRepository(
>     $this->get('csa_guzzle.client.mce')
> );
> // This obviously works everywhere
> $repositoryWithNewDefaultClient = new BaseRepository(
>     new GuzzleHttp\Client()
> );
> ```
>
> Furthermore injecting the service container into a class violates the
>   dependency inversion you try to achieve by using the Service Container
>   in the first place. This means, instead of making your repository
>   `ContainerAware` you should only add the services you need in that
>   repository, not the whole container. Just as you do in the 2nd example
>   with the Guzzle-client.
>
> Some people argue it's okay for controllers to violate that principle,
>   but I personally prefer [controller's being defined as services][1] to
>   be able to quickly see which dependencies they have by looking at the
>   constructor.
>
> As a general rule I would avoid using the ContainerAwareInterface.
>
> [1]: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Thank you.

So, it would be the better solution, if i inject only the guzzleClient, right?
As you can see, i have a few classes that extends from my BaseRepository and they need the guzzleClient.

But how is it possible to inject the guzzleClient for this scenario? If the programmer only want to create his basic "MyRep" Repositoryclass in the controller without any params.

services.yml

```
myapp.base_repository:
    class: MyApp\ApplicationBundle\Repository\BaseRepository
    arguments: ['@csa_guzzle.client.mce']
```

BaseRepository:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
class BaseRepository
{
    private $client = null;
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        var_dump($client);
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public getClient() {
       return $this->client;
    }
}
```

MyRepository:

```
MyRep extends BaseRepository:
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    class BaseRepository
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            var_dump($this->getClient());
        }
    }
```

Thank you!